# Assign html id attribute to ggplotly plot

Tags: r, r-plotly, ggplotly

Is there a way to assign a HTML id attribute to a plot generated via `ggplotly` (and rendered in Rmarkdown)?

I am looking for something like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(gg, id = "myid")
```

This throws an error as there is not an `id` argument for this function.

Comment: Can you explain what is it that you're trying to achieve by assigning an id?

Comment: @M-- I would like to be able to further format it via css, for instance; or manipulate it via javascript.

Comment: You can set the id when rendering: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1703 I am not sure if this can be done in any other way

Answer (score 0):

`ggplotly` seems to be frugal with ID assignments (except for the top level htmlwidgets container), but it does use a variety of specific css classes for the plot components (e.g. class `plot-container` or `main-svg`). You can identify these classes with your browsers document inspector (open with F12 and activate the selector tool).

As long as there's only one `ggplotly` output on your page, the class might be as useful as an ID for CSS selection, e.g.`$(.main-svg)` instead of `$(#myid)`. For more objects, it'll be some indexing trial-and-error.

Comment: Thank you for this information. The problem is that I have several plots, and this is precisely why I would like to assign each of them a unique identifier.